# How to match a repeated pattern within two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the string:

```
a:4:{i:1;s:2:"on";i:2;N;i:3;s:2:"on";i:4;N;}
```

It looks like JSON, but it's not. I need to turn this into the following array using a regular expression:

```
["On", N, "On", N]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: how exactly do you define your match: any occurrence of `"on"` and `N`, `"on"` and `N` separated by (informally) a key/value item (`i:2`) or sth entirely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is an array that was serialized using PHP serialize(). If, as it appears, you are getting this from a PHP program, you should instead unserialize it before giving it to your Javascript.

For example, at the host:

```
$json = json_encode( unserialize( $array));
```

Now your Javascript program can just use:

```
var array = JSON.parse(unserialized JSON from host);
```

and use it as a normal Javascript array.

Comment: This actually led me to the solution of the unserialize method that has been created in JavaScript for unserializing data after running the PHP serialize.